# How can I monitor the average number of lines added to a file per second in a bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'd like to monitor the average rate at which lines are being added to a log file in a bash shell.

I can currently monitor how many lines are in the file each second via the command

```
watch -n 1 'wc -l log.txt'
```

However, this gives me the total count of lines when I would prefer a rate instead. In other words, I would like a command to every so often output the number of lines that have been added to the file since the command was executed divided by the number of seconds the command has been running.

Comment: At StackOverflow, it is considered very important to show the code that you have tried and the problems you are having with it.  Since you edit removed that, I just rolled it back.  Feel free to improve your question, if you like, but do keep the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a rough count of lines per second, try:

```
tail -f log.txt | { count=0; old=$(date +%s); while read line; do ((count++)); s=$(date +%s); if [ "$s" -ne "$old" ]; then echo "$count lines per second"; count=0; old=$s; fi; done; }
```

(Bash required.)

Or, as spread out over multiple lines:

```
tail -f log.txt | {   
    count=0
    old=$(date +%s)
    while read line
    do
        ((count++))
        s=$(date +%s)
        if [ "$s" -ne "$old" ]
        then
            echo "$count lines per second"
            count=0
            old=$s
        fi
    done
}
```

This uses `date` to record the time in seconds.  Meanwhile, it counts the number of lines produced by `tail -f log.txt`.  Every time another second passes, the count of lines seen during that second is printed.

#### Demonstration

One one terminal, run the command:

```
while sleep 0.1; do echo $((count++)); done >>log.txt
```

This command writes one line to the file `log.txt` every roughly tenth of a second.

In another terminal, run:

```
$ tail -f log.txt | { count=0; old=$(date +%s); while read line; do ((count++)); s=$(date +%s); if [ "$s" -ne "$old" ]; then echo "$count lines per second"; count=0; old=$s; fi; done; }
15 lines per second
10 lines per second
10 lines per second
10 lines per second
9 lines per second
10 lines per second
```

Due to buffering, the first count is off.  Subsequent counts are fairly accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Simple script you can deploy:

```
Filename="log.txt"
ln_1=`wc -l $Filename | awk '{print $1}'`

while true
do
    ln_2=${ln_1}
    sleep 1
    ln_1=`wc -l $Filename | awk '{print $1}'`
    echo $(( ln_1-ln_2 )) lines increased
done
```

Comment: another variation over wc command. do understand, this will continouosly read *all* file content. This will do unnesessary system load, if observed file is big.

Answer (score 0):

The `tail` command supports watching for appended lines via `--follow` option, which accepts a file descriptor, or file name. With this option, `tail` periodically checks for file changes. The interval of the checks depends on whether kernel supports `inotify`. Inotify-based implementations detect the changes promptly (I would say, almost instantly). If, however, the kernel doesn't support `inotify`, `tail` resorts to periodic checks. In the latter case, `tail` sleeps for one second by default. The sleep interval can be changed with `--sleep-interval` option.

I wouldn't rely on the sleep interval in calculations, however:

> When ‘tail’ uses inotify, this polling-related option is usually ignored.

Especially because Bash has a built-in seconds counter, the `SECONDS` variable (see `info bash SECONDS`):

> This variable expands to the number of seconds since the shell was started.  Assignment to this variable resets the count to the value assigned, and the expanded value becomes the value assigned plus the number of seconds since the assignment.

Thus, you can initialize `SECONDS` to `1`, run a loop reading the output of `tail`, and calculate the speed as `number_of_lines / $SECONDS`. But this will produce average for the entire execution time. Average for the last `N` seconds is much more practical. It is also easy to implement, as Bash allows to reset the seconds counter.

**Example**

The following example implements the idea. The also features `watch`-like output in interactive mode.

```
# The number of seconds for which we calculate the average speed
timespan=8

# The number of lines
lines=0

# We'll assume that the shell is running in interactive mode,
# if the standard output descriptor (1) is attached to the terminal.
# See http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/intandnonint.html
if [ -t 1 ]; then
  is_interactive=1
  format='%d lines/sec'
else
  is_interactive=
  format='%d lines/sec\n'
fi

# Reset the built-in seconds counter.
# Also, prevent division by zero in the calculation below.
SECONDS=1

# Save cursor position, if interactive
test -n "$is_interactive" && tput sc

while read line; do
  if [[ $(( $SECONDS % $timespan )) -eq 0 ]]; then
    SECONDS=1
    lines=0
  fi

  if test -n "$is_interactive"; then
    # Restore cursor position, then delete line
    tput rc; tput el1
  fi
  printf "$format" $(( ++lines / SECONDS ))
done < <(tail -n0 -F log.txt)
```

*P.S.*

There are many other ways to get an offset in seconds. For example, you can fetch the current Unix time using the built-in `printf` function:

```
# -1 represents the current time
# %s is strftime's format string for the number of seconds since the Epoch
timestamp=$(builtin printf '%(%s)T' -1)
```

Another way is to invoke the `date` command: `date +%s`.

But I believe that reading from the `SECONDS` variable is faster and cleaner.

Comment: for modern tail command version, usually enough is -F option instead -f . In that scenario, when log file names will rotate, then minor number for file name will change. This is info for tail, it must reopen observed file.